# how to make a file with AWK from different lines

Tags: awk

I have a file(pdb)like this:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU A   2       6.630  12.294  -1.457  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      2  CA  LEU A   2       7.613  12.686  -0.404  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      8  CD2 LEU A   2       7.005  14.461   2.993  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     20  N   SER A   3       9.372  11.018  -0.564  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     21  CA  SER A   3      10.112   9.794  -0.130  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     22  C   SER A   3       9.128   8.620   0.057  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     31  N   PRO A   4       8.542   8.135  -1.026  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     32  CA  PRO A   4       7.582   7.018  -0.934  1.00  0.00           C
```

I need to take the first line with N atom and skipping the next one and taking the following one: the output matrix will looks like this, How can I do it with awk or other command?

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU A   2       6.630  12.294  -1.457  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     31  N   PRO A   4       8.542   8.135  -1.026  1.00  0.00           N
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your requirement correctly it should be as simple as

```
awk '$3 == "N"{++x; if (x % 2) print}' file
```